# Using Pixi.js v4 and RenderTexture, I can't figure out how to render a Graphics object to a Sprite

Tags: pixi.js

The gist of my problem is I'm generating a ton of Graphics objects, and my fps tanks when there get to be too many.  So I figured if I could get them rendered as textures using the RenderTexture class, I could then use the ParticleContainer for improved performance.  However, the objects that I am trying to render just don't show up on the screen any more.  See code below.

```
var poly = new PIXI.Polygon(points);            
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0x7647a2);
graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x7647a2, 1);
graphics.drawShape(poly);

var filter = new PIXI.filters.BlurFilter();
filter.blur = 2;
graphics.filters=[filter];

var rt = PIXI.RenderTexture.create(rx, ry);
renderer.render(graphics, rt);
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(rt);
stage.addChild(sprite);
```

My guess is that creating a sprite with a RenderTexture just doesn't work, but I can't find anything online that shows how to go about this.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Omitting the RenderTexture/Sprite code, and setting the graphics objects field 'cacheAsBitmap' to true has solved my issue for now, but I am not sure if I am satisfied with this solution.

Comment: I received an answer back from GoodBoyDigital saying the code looks fine, so its a bug in pixijs.

Comment: Creating a sprite with a RenderTexture most definately works. In fact, that's what RenderTexture is meant for. I just tested your code, and it works fine for me. The only thing missing from your code is the stage rendering at the end: `renderer.render(stage);` If that's not your issue, then you should check your console log for errors. How do you define {rx, ry}?